# Avoiding a for loop in R in an attempt to evaluate percentage of true positives/negatives when using logistic regression

Tags: r, logic

What I got: A matrix where I got the predicted probability of an outcome (from a logistic regression model) and the known outcome. For those curious I actually got two regression models and an independent test dataset where I wish to compare these two models by doing this.

```
> head(matrixComb)
      probComb outComb
[1,] 0.9999902       1
[2,] 0.9921736       0
[3,] 0.9901175       1
[4,] 0.9815581       0
[5,] 0.7692992       0
[6,] 0.7369990       0
```

What I want: A graph where I can plot how often my prediction model yields correct outcomes (one line for positives and one line for negatives) as a function of the cut off value for the probability. My problem is that I am unable to figure out how to do this without switching to Perl and use to For-loop to iterate through the matrix.

In Perl I would just start at probability 0.1 and in reach run of the for-loop increase the value by 0.1. In the first iteration I would count all probabilities <0.1 and outcome = 0 as true negatives, probability < 0.1 and outcome 1 as false negatives probability > 0.1 and outcome = 0 as false positives and probability > 0.1 and outcome = 1 as true positives.

The process would then be repeated and the results of each iteration would be printed as [probability, true positives/total positives, true negatives/total negatives]. Thus make it easy for me to print it out in open office calc.

The reason that I am asking this is that the operation is too complex for me to find a similar case here on stackoverflow or in a tutorial. But I would really like to learn a way to do this in an efficient manner in the R environment.

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the many ROC functions?

Comment: Because I am not good enough with R to know what to look for ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get R to draw the curves which are based on ROC analysis.  This is a crude version using the `ROCR` package and could easily be made prettier

```
ss <- 1000   # sample size
mydf <- data.frame(probComb = runif(ss)) # predictions illustration
mydf$outComb <- 0 + (runif(ss) < mydf$probComb) # actuals illustration

library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(mydf$probComb, mydf$outComb)
perfp <- performance(pred, "tpr")
perfn <- performance(pred, "tnr")
plot(perfp, col="green", ylab="True positive (green) and true negative (red) rates")
plot(perfn, col="red", ylab="True negative rate", add=TRUE)
```

to produce

[image]

If you must, you can find the data in `perfp` and `perfn`.

Comment: Intuitively this looks wrong when I work with it. To me it looks like this data doesn't use the "outcome" column and instead calculate "true positives" as the positives which are above the cutoff value and "positives" as all object with value above 0 probability. This is good for studying probability distribution but not the prediction accuracy at different cut off values.

And for any other R-apprentice, if you got a matrix you need to convert the matrix to a datafram for the answer to work. I Used: dfMatrixComb=as.data.frame(matrixComb)

Comment: @Tomas: It counts "true positives" as those with 1 as `outComb` and with `probComb` above the cutoff, and divides this by the total number with 1 as `outComb` to get the "true positive rate".  You don't need to use a dataframe for the `pred <- prediction(mydf$probComb, mydf$outComb)`; you can adapt this to use matrix columns or vectors if you prefer.

Comment: Then it's not running as I planned it, I apologize if I was unclear in my initial posts. True positives are correct with 1 as outComb and probComb above cut off. 

But the "Positives" should be the total number of objects above cut off not number of outComb (i.e. outComb is the correct classification and ProbComb is what I am testing).

Comment: @Tomas: what you are looking for is probably "positive predictive value" (or "precision") and similarly "negative predictive value".  The same code will work, except you should use `ppv` instead of `tpr`, and `npv` instead of `tnr`; you will also want to change the label.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it delivers exactly what I was looking for. Sadly it looks like my project failed spectacularily :P

I am however extremely thankful that you made me find the ROCR package which I am certain will be useful in future project. Have you used other resources than the teams webpage (http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/) to learn it? It would be good for future reference.

Comment: There is the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/ROCR.pdf).  You may also find the Wikipedia page on [Receiver operating characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do this manually:

```
#Create some sample data
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(100),y=sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE))

#Function to compute tp and tn
myFun <- function(x){
    tbl <- table(dat$x > x,dat$y)
    marg <- margin.table(tbl,2)
    tn <- tbl[1,1]/marg[1]
    tp <- tbl[2,2]/marg[2]
    rs <- c(tp,tn)
    names(rs) <- c('truePos','trueNeg')
    return(rs)
}


#Decision thresholds
thresh <- seq(0.1,0.9, by = 0.1)
#Loop using lapply
temp <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(thresh,myFun)))
temp$thresh <- thresh

#Melt and plot using ggplot
tempMelt <- melt(temp,id.vars="thresh")
ggplot(tempMelt,aes(x=thresh,y=value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group=variable,colour=variable))
```

[image: plot1]

Alternatively, as mentioned above in the comments, there are a plethora or ROC functions in R which can be found using `??ROC`. For example, using `roc` from the `caret` package:

```
temp <- as.data.frame(roc(dat$x,factor(dat$y)))
tempMelt <- melt(temp,id.vars="cutoff")
ggplot(tempMelt,aes(x=cutoff,y=value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group=variable,colour=variable))
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: I tried your solution but it turns out that I am too poor at handling R functions which made Henrys solution easier to follow. I will however try to learn the ggplot package in the future

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
# A function for counting outcomes for a certain probability
f <- function(d, p) {
  lp <- d$prob < p
  c(TNeg=sum(lp & d$out==0), TPos=sum(!lp & d$out==1))
}

# Make it accept a vector of probabilities
vf <- Vectorize(f, 'p')

# Sample data
n <- 100
d <- data.frame(prob=runif(n), out=round(runif(n)))
# Probabilities to plot
p <- seq(0,1, len=20)

res <- vf(d, p)
colnames(res) <- paste('p(', p, ')', sep='')
matplot(p, t(res), type='l', xlab='prob', ylab='count')
```

Comment: I just want to say that I love you all. I did not even dare to hope that my question would be answered by the time I wake up. I'll get right too it when I get home. Thanks!